# Parallel.foreach - Downloading images from Active Directory and saving it to folder. Is it thread safe

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel.foreach

I have a method:GetThumbnailPhotoForProfile() to which I pass a `list<EmployeeInfo>` which has few properties like FirstName,LastName and EmailAddress. Within the method I am using the following code which based on each email address connects to the Active Directory and fetches the profile image and saves it to a location (C:\Temp:\Images)

```
private bool GetThumbnailPhotoForProfile(List<EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfoList)
{

Parallel.ForEach(employeeInfoList.Select(emp=>emp.EmailAddress).ToList(),emailAddress =>
{
  var thumbnail = emailAddress.GetThumbnailPhoto();

  if (thumbnail != null)
  {
    thumbnail.Save("C:\Test\Images\" + emailAddress + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  }
  else
  {
    Log.Information("Thumbnail photo is not available for the {EmailAddress}.", emailAddress);
  }  

});
```

}

I initially used foreach loop and found that the method was taking more time, then I updated the code to use Parallel.ForEach and found that it is taking less time. I tested it many times and found the same performance difference.
Here I want to know whether the above method is thread safe and efficient or is there any better way to implement it.

Can anyone please guide me here.

Comment: Surely the Parallel construct will turn the linear for loop into a multi threaded for loop and as such it has to be thread safe?

Comment: Do you see any issues with the code above? I want to know is it thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

The question whether the code is thread safe cannot be answered based on just the code you showed. It depends on what exactly `GetThumbnailPhoto()` and `Save()` do and possibly on how `EmployeeInfoList` is constructed.

Comment: EmployeeInfoList: It is a list of class EmployeeInfo which contains Employeeinfo that I get from database. I pass that list to GetThumbnailPhotoForProfile which in turn invokes another extension mehod: GetThumbnailPhoto() where I connect to AD and fetch the thmbnailphoto of each profile and then save it to filesystem